# How can I round a numeric value?

Tags: ruby

I'm developing a rails 3.0.9 app and I'm doing some calculations for prices.

I need to do the following:

If I get (i.e.) 10.0 to 10.4 I need to store 10
If I get (i.e.) 10.5 to 10.9 I need to store 11

Is there a Ruby way to do this?

Comment: Reading documentation is good way to knowledge such thinks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the round method:

```
10.6.round  # => 11
10.4.round  # => 10
```

it will approximate your float to the nearest integer.

Answer (score 4):

In ruby, Fixnum and Float have a `round` method:

```
irb(main):009:0> 9.6.round
=> 10
irb(main):010:0> 9.4.round
=> 9
```